# VIF calculation in Julia

Tags: julia, variance

Is there a package that can calculate the Variance Inflation Factor ([VIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor)) in Julia, similar to `VIF` from the `fmsb` package in R? If there isn't, how would I do it manually (I'm still quite confused by all the Julia Statistics packages and what assumptions they make)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a package or function to do it but I figured out a way to do it manually:

```
using RDatasets, DataFrames, CSV, GLM
airquality = rename(dataset("datasets", "airquality"), "Solar.R" => "Solar_R")
model = lm(@formula(Wind ~ Temp+ Solar_R), airquality)
print(1/(1-r2(model)))
```

This returns 1.267492 which is the same as `VIF(lm(Wind ~ Temp+Solar.R, data=airquality))` in R

Comment: You may be able to use RDatasets.jl to get this dataset within Julia?